# powershell get info about computer

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

I'm trying to create a powershell script (getting more advanced... JK. Powershell offers more features than the batch file, and I want to use some of them.)

So, here's my batch script:

```
:Start 
@echo off 
set /p password="Password:" 
:Nextcomp 
set /p computer="Computer name:" 
wmic /user:username /password:%password% /node:"%computer%" memorychip get capacity 
set /P c=Do you want to get info about another computer (y/n)? 
if /I "%c%" EQU "y" goto :Nextcomp 
if /I "%c%" EQU "n" goto :End goto :choice 
pause 
:End
```

And here's what I found: [Script](https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/powershell/132/get-system-info-remotely.html)
I modified it for my needs, but whenever I try to run this script, I get it the wrong way - it's displaying me the entire script, and only in the end is it asking me about the computer name:

```
$resultstxt = "C:\Users\user\Documents\results.csv"
Param(
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, HelpMessage="Password?")]
     [SecureString]$password
   )
$pw = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($password))
$Computer = Read-Host -Prompt 'Computer name'
$out = @()
If (!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -Quiet)) { 
    Write-Host "$Computer not on network."
    Continue 
}
foreach($object in $HostList) {
$RAM = get-wmiobject -user user -password $pw -computername $object.("Computer")-class win32_physicalmemory 
$DeviceInfo= @{}
$DeviceInfo.add("RAM", "$([math]::floor($RAM.Capacity/ (1024 * 1024 * 1024 )) )" + " GB" )
$DeviceInfo.add("Computer Name", $vol.SystemName)
$out += New-Object PSObject -Property $DeviceInfo | Select-Object "RAM"
Write-Verbose ($out | Out-String) -Verbose             
$out | Export-CSV -FilePath $resultstxt -NoTypeInformation
```

}

As you might have guessed, I have a lot more fields, but they all are similar, and I borrowed from a lot of sources, but mainly from the "Script" link.

What I want is:

1. Hide the password
2. Export the information to CSV, with each new computer (see 3.) added following the current computer (on the next line)
3. Ask if I want to get the info about another computer, with "y" key for yes, "n" for no.
4. Make the script work

I found about the problem 1, but I haven't tested it yet, so... will it work? Next, I found about problem 2, but it would display all info in a not-easy-to-read format, and not everything I need, and all in one cell. Finally, about 3, I found, but it wouldn't work. I can't say I dug the entire Internet, but I'm hoping you guys (and gals?) can help me figure it out. It shouldn't be that hard to resolve these 3 issues, it's not a super complicated script after all, right? My current script is only 31 lines, including the whitespaces.

Comment: is a password or user name NEEDED on your setup for this? on most networks you can simply run the CIM/WMI cmdlet and it will use the current account info to access the systems.

Comment: If you don't plan to call this script with parameters, omit the start param block. Where is `$HostList` defined? If you don't want to get the whole script shown in every execution save it at least once.

Comment: I tried to run without the password, and it won't work: + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

Answer (score 0):

this is a demo of one way to get basic system info from a group of systems. it uses the CIM cmdlets since they are faster than the WMI cmdlets [most of the time], present datetime info as standard datetime objects, AND not somewhat deprecated.

it also uses the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet for remote parallelism, and is set to ignore errors so that non-responding systems don't waste your time.

```
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

# fake reading in a list of computer names
#    in real life, use Get-Content or (Get-ADComputer).Name
$ComputerList = @'
Localhost
BetterNotBeThere
127.0.0.1
10.0.0.1
::1
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

$IC_ScriptBlock = {
    $CIM_ComputerSystem = Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_ComputerSystem
    $CIM_BIOSElement = Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_BIOSElement
    $CIM_OperatingSystem = Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem
    $CIM_Processor = Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_Processor
    $CIM_LogicalDisk = Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_LogicalDisk |
        Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $CIM_OperatingSystem.SystemDrive}

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        LocalComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        Manufacturer = $CIM_ComputerSystem.Manufacturer
        Model = $CIM_ComputerSystem.Model
        SerialNumber = $CIM_BIOSElement.SerialNumber
        CPU = $CIM_Processor.Name
        SysDrive_Capacity_GB = '{0:N2}' -f ($CIM_LogicalDisk.Size / 1GB)
        SysDrive_FreeSpace_GB ='{0:N2}' -f ($CIM_LogicalDisk.FreeSpace / 1GB)
        SysDrive_FreeSpace_Pct = '{0:N0}' -f ($CIM_LogicalDisk.FreeSpace / $CIM_LogicalDisk.Size * 100)
        RAM_GB = '{0:N2}' -f ($CIM_ComputerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory / 1GB)
        OperatingSystem_Name = $CIM_OperatingSystem.Caption
        OperatingSystem_Version = $CIM_OperatingSystem.Version
        OperatingSystem_BuildNumber = $CIM_OperatingSystem.BuildNumber
        OperatingSystem_ServicePack = $CIM_OperatingSystem.ServicePackMajorVersion
        CurrentUser = $CIM_ComputerSystem.UserName
        LastBootUpTime = $CIM_OperatingSystem.LastBootUpTime
        }
    }

$IC_Params = @{
    ComputerName = $ComputerList
    ScriptBlock = $IC_ScriptBlock
    ErrorAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
    }
$RespondingSystems = Invoke-Command @IC_Params
$NOT_RespondingSystems = $ComputerList.Where({
    # these two variants are needed to deal with an ipv6 localhost address
    "[$_]" -notin $RespondingSystems.PSComputerName -and
    $_ -notin $RespondingSystems.PSComputerName
    })

# if you want to remove the PSShowComputerName, PSComputerName & RunspaceID props, use ... 
#    Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty PSShowComputerName, PSComputerName, RunspaceId


'=' * 40
$RespondingSystems
'=' * 40
$NOT_RespondingSystems
```

truncated output ...

```
LocalComputerName           : [MySysName]
Manufacturer                : System manufacturer
Model                       : System Product Name
SerialNumber                : System Serial Number
CPU                         : AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 945 Processor
SysDrive_Capacity_GB        : 931.41
SysDrive_FreeSpace_GB       : 745.69
SysDrive_FreeSpace_Pct      : 80
RAM_GB                      : 8.00
OperatingSystem_Name        : Microsoft Windows 7 Professional 
OperatingSystem_Version     : 6.1.7601
OperatingSystem_BuildNumber : 7601
OperatingSystem_ServicePack : 1
CurrentUser                 : [MySysName]\[MyUserName]
LastBootUpTime              : 2019-01-24 1:49:31 PM
PSComputerName              : [::1]
RunspaceId                  : c1b949ef-93af-478a-b2cf-e44d874c5724

========================================
BetterNotBeThere
10.0.0.1
```

to get a well structured CSV file, send the `$RespondingSystems` collection to the file via `Export-CSV`.

---

for a demo of a loop to wrap around any given block of code, take a look at this ...

```
$Choice = ''

while ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Choice))
    {
    $Choice = Read-Host 'Please enter a valid computer name or [x] to exit '
    # replace below with real code to check if $ComputerName is valid
    if ($Choice -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME)
        {
        $ValidCN = $True
        }
        else
        {
        $ValidCN = $False
        }
    if (-not $ValidCN -and $Choice -ne 'x')
        {
        # insert desired error notice
        [console]::Beep(1000, 300)
        Write-Warning ''
        Write-Warning ('Your choice [ {0} ] is not a valid computer name.' -f $Choice)
        Write-Warning '    Please try again ...'
        pause
        $Choice = ''
        }
        elseif ($Choice -ne 'x')
        {
        # insert code to do the "ThingToBeDone"
        Write-Host ''
        Write-Host ('Doing the _!_ThingToBeDone_!_ to system [ {0} ] ...' -f $Choice)
        pause
        $Choice = ''
        }
    }
```

on screen output ...

```
Please enter a valid computer name or [x] to exit : e
WARNING: 
WARNING: Your choice [ e ] is not a valid computer name.
WARNING:     Please try again ...
Press Enter to continue...: 
Please enter a valid computer name or [x] to exit : [MySysName]

Doing the _!_ThingToBeDone_!_ to system [ [MySysName] ] ...
Press Enter to continue...: 
Please enter a valid computer name or [x] to exit : x
```

Comment: I think you got me wrong. I don't want to create a list of computers and use that list to get the info about the computers in it. I want to be able to enter a computer name and get the info on that specific computer. Then, once I get the info about it, I want to get a message whether I want to get info about another computer, on "y" key, and so on, until I hit "n" which stands for "no" and as such, cancel. Many computers may be unavailable at the time I'll be trying to get the info about them, and if the computer is unavailable, I'd like to learn about it not from the file, but "real-time".

Comment: @user10864312 - wrap a `while` loop around the code and it will give you the same result for just one system. what i showed was a demo of how to get the info without requiring one to make several transfers of info ... run it on the  remote box, gather the info there, filter out what you actually want, and then send back only the data you desire. otherwise you will be sending info across your net that you will toss out since you rarely want more than a few props from any given CIM/WMI call.

Comment: Sorry to seem stupid, but I don't have a lot of experience with powershell. Wrap the "while" loop around which part of code? It may take me hours to test, so it's easier to ask... And... if I wrap it, will I get a request on computer name to get info about?

Comment: @user10864312 - ah! i did't realize your newness at this. [*grin*] i added a demo of a `while` loop for getting user input. if that works as needed, then i will go back and remove the off-topic data gathering code if you want that cleared up.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply, but... I just now had a chance to check the code. Here's what I wrote to the end of the file: $RespondingSystems | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\user\Documents\results.csv and the resulting document - the CSV file - is empty. Completely empty. Even its size is 0 bytes. Am I doing something wrong? Just like I said, I use what I find, no experience in coding with Powershell at all. (I know '$' creates a variable, but the same thing I can say about any computer programming language - I know 'if' and 'while' and a few other things, but that's pretty much it.)

Comment: (And for those who wants to say that Powershell is not a computer programming language, I know. This is just for comparison. I don't know Powershell scripting. I am barely familiar with  a bunch of functions, and that's it. Also, I don't know any programming languages.)

Comment: @user10864312 - [1] did the 1st set of code run AS IS on your system? did it produce output? [2] did the 2nd set of code run AS IS on your system? did it produce any output? [3] without seeing your code, i can't guess at what the problem is. you may want to create a new question with that code and a description of the new problem.

Comment: OK, just forget about it, I guess. I don't know how to make it work. Will try to figure it out by myself, I assume. I should have more or less enough info on how to write the script that should work, so... I will see how far I can go with the pieces of script from here and other places. Thanks for your help, that was a lot of lines of script. I just need to get it all together.

Comment: @user10864312 - when you get something that mostly works, you can always start a new question on that code behavior. good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: OK, thanks. I will see what I can do, and if I can't do anything about it - I will.