# How-to use best pass a scriptblock for 'Invoke-Command' from a 'Start-Job'

Tags: windows, powershell

I found a powershell example that does mostly what I need (Thanks to Lee_Dailey, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54469296/18171669).  <strike>However, the example runs **serially** on the list of machines, meaning that any powered-off machine will cause a timeout which at the moment looks like about 60s per machine.  With many machines being possibly offline, that could mean some long waits.  So I messed with the example to fetch the info per Start-Job & Invoke-Command.</strike>  I saw a suggestion from '@user4003407' that made sense to me (use Start-Job to call Invoke-Command) and I have a working version.

To make it work, however, I had to bring the script-block for the Invoke-Command down into the for-loop, which kinda bothers me as it gets initialized with every loop iteration.  I was therefore hoping someone might point me in the right direction for a method that might bring the scriptblock out of the for loop, such that it needs only be initialized once.  I've tried passing the scriptblock as a parameter, with $using:xxx, and a whole bunch of other ways, but I can't seem to make it work.

I admit herewith to being a powershell noob.

Thanks in advance.

```
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

param($myCSV = '.\getSysInfo.csv')

# fake reading in a list of computer names
<#
$ComputerList = @' 
jupiter
saturn
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine
#>

$ComputerList = Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(objectClass=computer)" -SearchBase 'OU=Servercomputers,OU=batcave,DC=gothham,DC=com' -Properties name | Select-Object -Property name | foreach { $_.name }

foreach ($computer in $ComputerList) {
    $running = @(Get-Job | Where-Object { $_.State -eq 'Running' })
    if ($running.Count -ge 16) {
        $running | Wait-Job -Any | Out-Null
    }
    
    $job = {
        $IC_ScriptBlock = {
            $CIM_ComputerSystem = Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_ComputerSystem
            $CIM_BIOSElement = Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_BIOSElement
            $CIM_OperatingSystem = Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem
            $CIM_Processor = Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_Processor
            $CIM_LogicalDisk = Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_LogicalDisk |
                Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $CIM_OperatingSystem.SystemDrive}
            $Win32_QuickFixEngineering = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_QuickFixEngineering -Property HotFixId | Select-Object -Property HotFixId
            $CIM_NetworkAdapter = Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_NetworkAdapter
            
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                LocalComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                Manufacturer = $CIM_ComputerSystem.Manufacturer
                Model = $CIM_ComputerSystem.Model
                SerialNumber = $CIM_BIOSElement.SerialNumber
                CPU = $CIM_Processor.Name
                SysDrive_Capacity_GB = '{0:N2}' -f ($CIM_LogicalDisk.Size / 1GB)
                SysDrive_FreeSpace_GB ='{0:N2}' -f ($CIM_LogicalDisk.FreeSpace / 1GB)
                SysDrive_FreeSpace_Pct = '{0:N0}' -f ($CIM_LogicalDisk.FreeSpace / $CIM_LogicalDisk.Size * 100)
                RAM_GB = '{0:N2}' -f ($CIM_ComputerSystem.TotalPhysicalMemory / 1GB)
                OperatingSystem_Name = $CIM_OperatingSystem.Caption
                OperatingSystem_Version = $CIM_OperatingSystem.Version
                OperatingSystem_BuildNumber = $CIM_OperatingSystem.BuildNumber
                OperatingSystem_ServicePack = $CIM_OperatingSystem.ServicePackMajorVersion
                CurrentUser = $CIM_ComputerSystem.UserName
                LastBootUpTime = $CIM_OperatingSystem.LastBootUpTime
                HotFixes = $Win32_QuickFixEngineering.HotFixId -join '; '
                NetworkAdapter_Name = $CIM_NetworkAdapter.Name -join '; '
            }
        }

        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $args[0] -ScriptBlock $IC_ScriptBlock -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'
    }
    #Write-Host "Starting job for $computer"
    Start-Job -Name $computer -ScriptBlock $job -ArgumentList $computer | Out-Null
}
Write-Host "Waiting for jobs to complete..."

# Wait for all jobs to complete and results ready to be received
Wait-Job -Name $ComputerList | Out-Null
# Get-Job *
$RespondingSystems = Receive-Job -Name $ComputerList
Remove-Job -Name $ComputerList
$RespondingSystems | Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty PSShowComputerName, PSComputerName, RunspaceId | Export-Csv -Path $myCSV -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'

$NOT_RespondingSystems = $ComputerList.Where({
    $_ -notin $RespondingSystems.LocalComputerName
})
Write-Host "`nNon-Responding Systems: "
$NOT_RespondingSystems
```

Comment: Invoke to all servers at once and redirect the error stream to success stream and then filter by error record

Comment: the code i posted in the Question you linked to ... does not run _serially_. it runs the query in parallel by handing a list of systems AND a scriptblock to the `Invoke-Command` call. ///// why on earth are you running a JOB that contains an `Invoke-Command` call? that makes no sense at all since the jobs will run locally and THEN call the I-C call to run the scriptblock _remotely_.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, you are very right concerning Invoke-Command running the tasks parallel - my bad, I assumed and didn't verify.  Thank you for the correction.
Start-Job: I stumbled across a statement that asserted it was better to control the jobs locally and to then execute what one would need remotely.  It sounded good at the time, but I have no invest either way, just trying to learn.

Comment: @grenlow - jobs are fairly resource intensive and - usually - run locally. so your code seems to run one local session AND one remote session for each system. bad idea ... just use the remote sessions. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting a local job that holds the invocation to remote host is very inefficient, [remote jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_jobs?view=powershell-7.2) on the other hand are highly efficient, your code can be simplified by simply allowing `Invoke-Command` take the array of computers and invoke the remote jobs in parallel, you can collect the result of all invocations and then filter by objects which are of the type [`ErrorRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.errorrecord?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0).

```
$ou = 'OU=Servercomputers,OU=batcave,DC=gothham,DC=com'
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $ou
$IC_ScriptBlock = { <# Original IC Scriptblock code here #> }
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock $IC_ScriptBlock 2>&1
$failed, $success = $result.where({
    $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] }, 'Split'
)

$success | Export-Csv .... -NoTypeInformation
$failed.Exception.Message # => Is the list of failed invocations
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer and insight.  
Would you say that there is no valid use-case in which Start-Job can be used to organize Invoke-Command for remote servers?  If there are none in your opinion, then I would give this answer its due.  Otherwise I would still be interested in a solution the original question.

Comment: @grenlow I would never consider doing that, it's inefficient, slow and you're consuming local resources when there is no reason for it